# Handling documents that don't belong to a collection in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application that was initially just using a local json server, but I started migrating to Firebase/Firestore recently. With my json server, I had an endpoint that retrieved just an object with the user's custom settings. Those settings will never need to be an array, it will always just be an object. How do I handle that in Firestore where every document is supposed to belong to a collection? Do I just create a collection that will always have 1 object inside? That seems kind of hacky, but I can't think of another solution and I am struggling to figure out how to search for the answer.

EDIT:
I have a lot more data than just this object. Most of my data are arrays that can get very long.

Comment: What about using Firebase realtime database instead? Its a JSON tree structure out of the box. Don't know which kind of data you have, and how often you need to access it, but if it's always an object and you don't want to create a collection just for that, maybe you can try that approach. Or maybe you can set that data inside another document where it makes sense to have it?

Comment: I have some arrays that have the potential to get really big, there are just a couple of examples of objects that don't logically belong in an array. Not sure if the realtime database makes sense for me just because of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a collection that has one document.  You are absolutely obliged to put a document in a collection.

My opinion: if all you have is one object to store, Cloud Firestore is massive overkill for that problem.  It's easy to put together, but you are going to pay for document reads that might be cheaper using something a little more straightforward than a massively scalable, cloud hosted, NoSQL, realtime database.

Comment: I have several other collections that can get quite large. I just happen to have a couple standalone objects as well and wasn't sure if there was a better way to handle those.

Comment: You have any number of ways to store a bit of data, but if you must use Cloud Firestore, your documents are going to have to live in a collection.